# Android Progress Bar Task Count

Tags: android, dialog, progress

I have an progress bar for displaying percentage of task being completed. Here is my screenshot: [image]

As you can see, the left text is OK. But I want the right text display the number of item being loaded, not percentage like the left one. For example, I have 200 item and I want the rigth text should display like: 13/200, 27/200....etc. How can I set this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "right text" is named "progress", and its maximum value can be set with the `progressBar.setMax(number)` method.

To show your progress from zero to max you could then do something like:

```
progressBar.setProgress(0);

for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    // Do stuff
    progressBar.incrementProgressBy(1);
}
```