# Displaying Loading count and Max count using Progress Bar in Android

Tags: android

In my application I want to display Progress Bar like Loading contacts with Total contacts count. I want like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zbw0.jpg

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460479/android-progress-bar-task-count

Comment: can you please explain what is "items.length".